# VB.Net Gridview to SQL table when datetime is null

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I am trying to insert gridview values to SQL table. However when date value is empty the query is showing error.When some value is entered in date value it accepts.I want the query to accept both null and actual value.
sample of the part of the query from gridview to SQL table

```
'" & Format(DateTime.Parse(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value.ToString), "MMM/dd/yyyy") & "',
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of the below suggestion may help you.

1. Eliminate null values before you fill the data in dgvData
2. Before using in the mentioned statement with problem, use linq or lambda statement to filter out the null values. After that use it to format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some conditions

```
If(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value is Nothing,Nothing,Format(DateTime.Parse(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value.ToString), "MMM/dd/yyyy") )
```

Or you have to use `IsDbNull()` function if `Is Nothing` is not working

```
If(IsDbNull(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value),Nothing,Format(DateTime.Parse(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value.ToString), "MMM/dd/yyyy") )
```

Comment: I tried modifying my query like this but no success   '" & IIf(IsDBNull(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value.tostring), "NULL", Format(DateTime.Parse(dgvData.Item("POLOG_DATE", i).Value.ToString), "MMM/dd/yyyy")) & "'.Receiving error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Please help.

Comment: You are wrting "NULL" as string!! You have to use `Nothing` instead of `"NULL"` DONT ADD DOUBLE QUOTES